# Characteristic function of a gaussian

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

There is a claim in my book, that the characteristic function of a Gaussian with mean $0$ and  variance $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$ is

$$ \phi(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{ixt}e^{-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t^2} \frac{\sigma dt}{\sqrt{2\pi}} $$

I just don't understand the presence of that $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ multiplying the measure. I would perfectly agree  with the result without that factor. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The density function of $\mathcal N(0,\sigma^{2})$ is $\frac  1 {\sqrt {2\pi} \sigma} e^{-x^{2}/2\sigma^{2}}$. For $\mathcal N(0,1/\sigma^{2})$ you just have to change $\sigma $ to $\frac  1 {\sigma}$ in this.